# match elements between two std::vectors

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, matching

I am writing a module that estimates optical flow. At each time step it consumes an std::vector where each element of the vector is a current pixel location and a previous pixel location. The vector is not ordered. New pixels that were previously not seen will be present and flow locations that were not found will be gone. Is there a correct way to match elements in the new vector to the set of optical flow locations being estimated?

The vectors are on the order of 2000 elements.

These are the approaches I am considering:

- naively iterate through the new vector for each estimated optical flow location
- naively iterating through the new vector but removing each matched location so the search gets faster as it goes on
- run std::sort on my list and the new list at every time step. Then iterate through the new vector starting at the last matched index +1

I'm suspecting that there is an accepted way to go about this but I don't have any comp sci training.

I'm in c++ 11 if that is relevant.

```
// each element in the new vector is an int. I need to check if 
// there are matches between the new vec and old vec
void Matcher::matchOpticalFlowNaive(std::vector<int> new_vec)
{
for(int i = 0; i < this->old_vec.size(); i++)
    for(int j =0; j < new_vec.size(); j++)
        if(this->old_vec[i] == new_vec[j]){
            do_stuff(this->old_vec[i],  new_vec[j])
            j = new_vec.size();
        }
}
```

Comment: some code please? [mcve]

Comment: @holmeski - not sure to understand but... are you sure that, instead a `std::vector`, `std::set` (or `std::multi_set`) isn't better for you?

Comment: You'd better express it in term of pure data. There is no concept of optical flow in c++. So you can't have a vector of it. You need to model real world data into c++ types, and then explain what exactly you want to extract from those two vectors. EDIT: your function does not make sense. It accepts `new_flow` only, where is `old_flow`?

Comment: @max66, sets do look better but that is not what I am being passed. I'll look into casting the new information into a set.

Comment: Can you use a set instead of your internal old_vec, at least?
Otherwise your choices are to either sort the vectors or copy them into a temporary set.
You could also consider a c++11 unordered_set

Comment: Sounds like yo want to find the intersection of two vectors. I suggest this article: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-union-and-intersection-of-two-unsorted-arrays/

Comment: @Valentin, this is exactly what i wanted. thank you.

Comment: @GemTaylor, the keys will change every time in this case so it looks like sets are out

Comment: it looks like std::set_intersection is what i was looking for

Answer (score 0):

Not sure to understand what do you need but, supposing that your `Matcher` is constructed with a vector of integer, that there ins't important the order and that you need check this vector with other vectors (method `matchOpticalFlowNaive()`) to do something when there is a match, I suppose you can write something as follows

```
struct Matcher
 {
   std::set<int> oldSet;

   Matcher (std::vector<int> const & oldVect)
      : oldSet{oldVect.cbegin(), oldVect.cend()}
    { }

   void matchOpticalFlowNaive (std::vector<int> const & newVec)
    {
      for ( auto const & vi : newVec )
       {
         if ( oldSet.cend() != oldSet.find(vi) )
            /* do something */ ;
       }
    }
 };
```

where the `Matcher` object is constructed with a vector that is used to initialize a `std::set` (or a `std::multi_set`, or a unordered set/multiset?) to make simple the work in `matchOpticalFlowNaive()`